# Print string with each letter having different color

Tags: javascript

I have been wondering if I can print a string with each letter having a different color.

If I can do this can anybody tell me how ?

Comment: Yes, you can. What's the problem?

Comment: Ok How to do this ? dbanet

Comment: Well print each letter enclosed into `<span>` with `style="color:#xxxxxx"` property where `x` iterates from `000000` to `FFFFFF`.

Comment: [an example I just made](http://jsbin.com/ceyohiro/1/)

Comment: Please see the guidelines for [what consists of an appropriate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: @dystroy well, nice code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly set the color (or any part of the style) of a letter, you have first to wrap it in its own element so that you can style it. Here's an example :

```
var e = document.getElementById('s');
e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.split('').map(function(l){
  return '<span style="color:#'
    +Math.floor(Math.random()*16777216).toString(16)
    +'">'+l+'<span>'
}).join('');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ceyohiro/3/edit)

Comment: +1. I was trying the [same thing](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/hM7aq/) :)

Comment: @tewathia FYI the `Number.prototype.toString()` receives the radix as its first argument, so you actually don't need the `['0'...'F']` array.